# Get detail like profile Picture and more Informations while Twitter login in IOS 10.2 using Fabric

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios10

How to get detail like profile Picture and more Informations while Twitter login in IOS using Fabric .
I write this code --

```
[[Twitter sharedInstance] logInWithCompletion:^
     (TWTRSession *session, NSError *error) {
         if (session) {
             /* Get user info */

             [[[Twitter sharedInstance] APIClient] loadUserWithID:[session userID]
                                                       completion:^(TWTRUser *user,
                                                                    NSError *error)
              {
                  // handle the response or error
                  if (![error isEqual:nil]) {
                      NSLog(@"Twitter info   -> user = %@ ",user);
                      NSString *urlString = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:user.profileImageLargeURL];
                      NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:urlString];
                      NSData *pullTwitterPP = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url];

                      UIImage *profImage = [UIImage imageWithData:pullTwitterPP];


                  } else {
                      NSLog(@"Twitter error getting profile : %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                  }
              }];


         } else {
             NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
         }
     }];
```

But it show this type of error:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the answer my self :

```
[[Twitter sharedInstance] logInWithCompletion:^
 (TWTRSession *session, NSError *error) {
     if (session) {

         NSLog(@"signed in as %@", [session userName]);
         /* Get user info */

         NSString *userID = [Twitter sharedInstance].sessionStore.session.userID;
         TWTRAPIClient *client = [[TWTRAPIClient alloc] initWithUserID:userID];
         [client loadUserWithID:userID completion:^(TWTRUser *user, NSError *error) {
             NSLog(@"Profile image url = %@", user.profileImageLargeURL);
         }];


     } else {
         NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
     }
 }];
```

It gives you url of profile Picture.